# Will Java Annotations make the performace slow because of reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, jersey

If we use Java annotations will the reflection apis be called everytime to analyze those annotations? Wont that make the execution slow?

By everytime I mean whenever that flow is executed.

Example Case: 
IN Jersey we use the annotations @Get which is used everytime there is a get request on server. Does that mean that with every get request the reflection apis analyze that class for that annotation?

Comment: I haven't checked  for `Jersey` but its possible to cache the reflection calls, thus avoiding extra cost of reflection on every call

Comment: I suggest you measure how much time is spent doing this, otherwise you would just be guessing. It could be 50% or 5% or 0.0005% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is the relative thing. It would be slow if you use reflection to perform simple math. But in case when you handle network requests the reflection overhead should be negligible.

Class annotations are analyzed only once during the class loading. After that they are stored in JVM data structures and it's relatively cheap to access them.

Comment: Thanks Tagir, can you suggest some books to get in-depth knowledge of JVM

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Jersey internals, but with other frameworks that I've used - some of them were able to optimized the annotation processing part, either by caching, and/or by doing it once when creating an instance of a long-lived service.

That's in addition to "Tagir Valeev"s correct note, that the annotation processing is negligible compared to I/O latency.